# How do I customize content in the WP starter theme Roots?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to WP and very new to Roots (http://roots.io/) and I am having trouble creating a custom home page. Here's how far (I think) I understand it:

- To create a custom home page I put a file named "front-page.php" in the WP root directory. This file is based off of "page.php".
- "front-page.php" loads "content-page.php" from the templates directory.

And that's where it gets a bit fuzzy to me. The function "the_content()" lives in "content-page.php" and I'm assuming it loads the content of the page but it's loading some default stuff (I think it's added by the Roots theme) that I don't want there. I don't think the proper way to customize the home page content is to modify "content-page.php" and remove or change the function "the_content()". I'm assuming there is a better, modular way to do this, possibly creating a custom class that will be loaded when "the_content()" is called but I don't know where and how to do that.

Comment: When you say you 'want to customize content' do you mean the markup of the content or the actual content (i.e. the copy/images etc)?

Comment: Both. Some markup and copy is being added by default. I would like to get rid of it and add my own.

Answer (score 0):

As you're a bit vague with the details I'm going to have to read between the lines a bit. If you need further clarification just ask:
`the_content()` just outputs the content stored for a particular post, which you would edit in the WP admin. In terms of editing the *markup* that surrounds the content you have a couple of options. You could edit `content-page.php` as you require, or create a new partial (such as `content-home.php` and load that instead.
You can also use *filters* for modifying content; these are often used to change content that appears in multiple places such as 'read more' links. Check out [this introduction to filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373) for more info.
In closing, you don't want/need to edit `the_content()`

Comment: Thanks. I think what I'm trying to do would be to create a new partial. Where would I put that? In the templates dir?

Comment: The Roots theme keeps partials in the `templates` directory. You would load the partial using `get_template_part('templates/your-partial')`. `get_template_part()` can accept a second variable, which is a bit confusing at first, so I'd recommend (reading this post which explains it in more detail)[http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/]